# How to send a query with parameters

Tags: java, php, android, sql

I want to execute an insertion query with some parameters in my android app.

For example in `php` it is something like:-

```
$query ="insert into inventoryproductrel(id, productid, sequence_no, quantity, listprice) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
$qparams = array($id,$prod['prod'],$counter,$prod['pcs'],$prod['price']);
$productadded=$adb->pquery($query,$qparams);
```

*Here `pquery` is a function:-*

```
function pquery($sql, $params){
    global $log, $default_charset;
    $log->debug('Prepared sql query being executed : '.$sql);
            $this->checkConnection();

            $this->executeSetNamesUTF8SQL();

            $sql_start_time = microtime(true);
            $params = $this->flatten_array($params);
            if (count($params) > 0) {
                $log->debug('Prepared sql query parameters : [' . implode(",", $params) . ']');
            }

            if($this->avoidPreparedSql || empty($params)) {
                $sql = $this->convert2Sql($sql, $params);
                $result = &$this->database->Execute($sql);
            } else {
                $result = &$this->database->Execute($sql, $params);
            }
            $sql_end_time = microtime(true);
            $this->logSqlTiming($sql_start_time, $sql_end_time, $sql, $params);

            $this->lastmysqlrow = -1;
            return $result;
}
```

**I don't know how to do this i.e. executing a query with parameters in java/android.**

Comment: Do you want to save data in a local sqlite database on your device or on an online server ?

Comment: @Shivam Verma online server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a POST Request from your Android Application to the same PHP Script and just before inserting the the value to the database, set the values of the variales from the POST Parameters.

Use the following code to make POST Requests. Make sure you do this from an AsyncTask or a separate thread :

```
public String makePOSTRequestNew(String urlString,
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(nameValuePairs));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        responseStreamReader.close();
        response = stringBuilder.toString();
        conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

The `getQuery()` Method creates a parameter String from the nameValuePairs :

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

And this is how you can call the method with the parameters you want to POST :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramName",
                            paramValue));
String insertResponse = makePOSTRequestNew(insertURL, nameValuePairs);
```

Comment: it is showing error("The method getQuery(List<NameValuePair>) is undefined") at line `writer.write(getQuery(nameValuePairs));`

Comment: What is being stored by `insertResponse` variable?

Comment: insertResponse stores the response of the POST Request.

Comment: Missed the getQueryMethod. Just added.

Comment: Where is the query that I am using for insertion of values, I mean where is the table name in which I will do the insertion??

Comment: you'll make this POST request to the same php script. The php script will handle the insertion. On the php side, you have to grab the values using $_POST['param_name'] and insert.

Comment: means it will automatically use this line:- `"insert into inventoryproductrel(id, productid, sequence_no, quantity, listprice) values(?,?,?,?,?)";`

Comment: Yeah. If you fetch the values from the POST Request and set it to the respective variables in php.

Comment: is it possible to make it a GET request?

Comment: Yes. Read up on how you can make get request in android.

Comment: can't I make the same code work as `GET` by changing the `POST` keywords? :P

Comment: You should be able to. But why not try first instead of asking ? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this way hope it will help you,

```
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("id", id);
        args.put("productid", productid);
        args.put("sequence_no", sequence_no);
        args.put("quantity", quantity);
        args.put("listprice", listprice );
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase database = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
            database.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, args, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what is `sd`? and will it work if I am not having a local database, I mean I am connecting to my database via url?